# Помогите решить проблему с unhashable type: 'Counter'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл в котором в каждой строчке два числа разделенных запятой: ID студента и ID решенной задачи. Пример:

```
1,2
1,4
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
```

Надо написать функцию, которая принимает имя файла и возвращает словарь, в котором для каждого студента будет указано количество решенных им задач. Для примера выше результатом будет:

```
{1:3, 2:4}
```

Код, который выдает ошибку:

```
import collections 
def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            s = line.split(',')
            a = ''.join(s)
            ss = collections.Counter(a)
    return {ss}
```

Comment: В вашем решении попробуйте изменить 4-ю строку на `for line in [_.replace('\n', '') for _ in f.readlines()]:`

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

res = dict(Counter(line.split(",")[0] for line in Path(filename).read_text().splitlines()))
```

---

Результат:

```
In [110]: res
Out[110]: {'1': 3, '2': 4}
```

---

**UPDATE:** Ответ в виде функции:

```
def fun(filename):
    return dict(Counter(int(line.split(",")[0]) for line in Path(filename)
                .read_text()
                .splitlines()))
```

Тестирование:

```
print(fun(r"C:\temp\data.txt"))
# {1: 3, 2: 4}
```

Comment: выдает ошибку...

Comment: @Helloitisme, какую ошибку?

Comment: нужно написать функцию через def и плюс обозначить filename, но даже если так сделать, все равно выходит ошибка

Comment: @Helloitisme,  у меня ошибка "не выходит". Можете пояснить как фраза `"все равно выходит ошибка"` отвечает на вопрос `"какую ошибку"`?

Comment: простите за мой сбивчивый язык
код, который изначально вы написали, я переделала в функцию, но stepik(мы там решаем задачки) не пропускает это решение, видимо это связано с импортируемыми модулями

Comment: Думаю, что проблема у топикстартера с Вашим вариантом, могла возникнуть в том, что ID студентов в вариантах исходников, могут не всегда быть чисто числовыми, поэтому stepik и не принимает ответ. Поскольку `int(line.split(",")[0])`

Comment: @Andrey, до этого был [ответ без преобразования к целым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1055599/revisions), который stepik не принимал ;)

Answer (score 1):

В последней строке уберите фигурные скобки, ошибка должна пропасть.

И, кажется, обработку строк файла нужно изменить так:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    s = line.split(',')
    a = s[0]
    ss = collections.Counter(a)
```

Comment: тоже не получается

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import collections

def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        a = collections.Counter([line.split(',')[0] for line in [_.replace('\n', '') for _ in f.readlines()]])
    return dict(a)
```